# Spring Boot - After upgrading from 2.2.5 to 2.5.7, application failed to start

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I upgraded spring boot from 2.2.5 to 2.5.7 and I'am using MongoDB. Since compilation failed i removed spring-boot-starter-mongo and i added below dependencies which resolved my compilation issues

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
  <artifactId>mongodb-driver</artifactId>
  <version>3.11.2</version>    
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
  <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
  <version>3.11.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
```

With all above changes if i run application i am facing ***java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoDatabaseFactory***

**Also adding runtime log:**

**Need inputs to resolve this issue**

```
2021-12-21 20:16:00.263 ERROR [ht-ui-api : ] 19004 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find class [org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoDatabaseFactory]
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:334) ~[spring-core-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.adapt(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:446) ~[spring-core-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.getValue(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:369) ~[spring-core-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.asMap(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:284) ~[spring-core-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AbstractMergedAnnotation.asAnnotationAttributes(AbstractMergedAnnotation.java:193) ~[spring-core-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.core.type.AnnotatedTypeMetadata.getAnnotationAttributes(AnnotatedTypeMetadata.java:106) ~[spring-core-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigUtils.attributesFor(AnnotationConfigUtils.java:285) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.determineBeanNameFromAnnotation(AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.java:102) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.generateBeanName(AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.java:81) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitionForImportedConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:169) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:150) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:129) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:343) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.7.jar:2.5.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:765) ~[spring-boot-2.5.7.jar:2.5.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:445) ~[spring-boot-2.5.7.jar:2.5.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.7.jar:2.5.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) ~[spring-boot-2.5.7.jar:2.5.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.7.jar:2.5.7]
    at com.htds.api.HtUiApiApplication.main(HtUiApiApplication.java:15) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.5.7.jar:2.5.7]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoDatabaseFactory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:468) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader.loadClass(RestartClassLoader.java:145) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.5.7.jar:2.5.7]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:468) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:284) ~[spring-core-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:324) ~[spring-core-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
```

- 

Comment: Hi @xerx593 , when i use <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
  </dependency>  It gave me compilation error Cannot find symbol : MongoClient and cannot find symblo for various classes of MongoDB and hence i used     <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>  which resolved my compilation issue . Now i am facing runtime error

Comment: that means: or you will resolve the compilation issues, or you will not upgrade (spring-boot)! ;(

Comment: I hope [this(offcial, correct version(s) upgrade guide)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#upgrading.2-3) helps!

Comment: and if you (today) upgrade spring-boot then "try all-in": `2.6.1`! ;)

Answer (score 1):

> Why you "upgrade spring boot to 2.5.7"? (why, today, not 2.6.1?;) But why do you leave spring-data-mongodb: **2.2.5.RELEASE** ?

##### Please align

I.e.: Confirm spring-data-mongodb version with spring-boot version (or vice versa)! In case of `2.5.7`, these would be:

- org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-sync:**4.2.3**
- org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:**3.2.7**

...[proof for both](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb/2.5.7/spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-2.5.7.pom). #

---

For upgrading spring-data-mongodb (**or not!**) `2.x -> 3.x`, (which is obviously required by upgrading to spring-boot:2.XXX), please refer to [Reference Documentation#upgrading.2-3](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#upgrading.2-3).

Hopefully also helpful: [(latest) Spring Boot Release Notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.6-Release-Notes) (with quick links to previous releases, <kbd>Ctrl+F</kbd>, `mongo`... `data`;)